# What are Kudos and Diamonds and how do I earn them?

Tags: airmech

[image: Kudos and Diamonds in top bar]

1. What are they?
2. What do they do?
3. How can I earn them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kudos and Diamonds are the two different currencies of AirMech used for buying things in the game.

---

### Kudos

Kudos ([image: Kudos Coin]) is the main currency of the game.

- It is earned by completing a game
  [image: Match Victory Screen]
- It is used to buy functional items in the game and some (very few) cosmetic items.
- Anything bought with Kudos can also be bought with Diamonds.

### Diamonds

Diamonds ([image: Diamond]) are the premium currency of the game (bought with real money).

- It can be earned by paying money or by the completion of certain quests (usually VIP only).  *There are many other ways to earn Diamonds through various in-game events.*
  [image: VIP Quest Rewards (With Silver VIP)]
- Diamonds can be used to buy (almost) anything in the game including cosmetic items.